# File Sharing over Sip

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, sip, pjsip

I am trying to find the best way regarding file sharing and video-audio call over SIP.

I am currently using a PJSIP stack for audio video calls + messaging. I know a file can be sent in chunks over sip using different mime type for each sent packet.

BUT in a standard proper way from what I read MSRP, XMPP would be the best solution.

I did find information about MSRP and XMPP.

Which one of these is better and why? Is there any client on android and iOS that has this protocol implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose XMPP for sure. Search about smack library. It works great and have built-in types to send chat, media or file.

You can read more about xmpp file transfer from [here](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/wiki/aSmack-XMPP-File-Transfer)

Good luck

Comment: For file transferring, would only sip stack work in case I m thinking of splitting the file in multiple chunks?